# I'm trying to run "3) extract images from video data_dst FULL FPS.bat" from DeepFaceLab and it only shows this message

Tags: python

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000030fc (most recent call first):

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What did you try? What did you implement? Where does your program crash...?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, uninstalled and extracted DeepFaceLab again. first installation corrupted the files.